# deploying an HttpModule for just a site collection

Tags: http-module

Is there anyway to deploy an HttpModule using a site-level feature (WSP) and for it to be active for that specific site collection only?

Answer (score 1):

No. An HttpModule is added to the HTTP pipeline for requests/responses for a particular web application, so it's a broader scope.

You could have a dedicated web application for a single site collection. Or you could check within the HttpModule that the site collection is one you want to process (I would consider storing some sort of flag in the SPSite.RootWeb's properties. Obviously, checking those for each request could have a detrimental impact on performance).